# Can salesforce use read (Get_Entity method) of OData

Tags: salesforce, odata

Very new to salesforce. We have an odata service call for getting the details of the product. The URL that was given to us was https://XXX/XXX/XXX.svc/ProductSet(Name='Product').

In salesforce is it possible to use this? Or can salesforce only user those with query operations ($filters)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about using Lightning Connect, right? Might be tricky

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=odata_query_string_options.htm&type=5

> Salesforce Connect supports only the following OData system query
>   options. All other options in the OData 2.0 and 4.0 specifications are
>   unused.

You could also use the tip from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations_remote_data_service.htm&type=5 (except the link is dead for me, maybe you need to Google around a bit)

> Validate your OData producer by using the Open Data Protocol Service
>   Validation Tool at services.odata.org/validation. Doing so checks your
>   implementation against the OData specification and identifies
>   potential issues.

Best would be to just try it out in sandbox or developer edition.

When all else fails you can try to write apex code to prettify the returned dataset. You send normal REST/SOAP callouts and have piece of apex code that wraps it in OData-compatible format, pretends to salesforce all's good. There are some limitations (Apex can do only 10 callouts in single transaction) and it's bit of "lipstick on a pig" but it's an option. Actual code samples are here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_examples.htm but you might want to explore the sidebar menu too.